# Set label from JSONSerialization result

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurlsession

I have a swift application `Swift 3` that interact with the server to get the data. Still now I can successfully be connected to the server. The problem is that when I want to get a specific data from the `JSON` result to set a label text value, I always got the value `Optional(x)` in the console and the label value is always `nil`.

This is the format of my data that I receive from the server:

```
[A: 1, 
 B: 2,
 C: 3]
```

And this is how I get it:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }
            self.labelA.text = json[“A”] as? String

        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

**Edit:**
I can also get those formats:

**Case 1:**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    fieldA: “nameA”,
    fieldB: [“textA”, “textB", “textC”, “textD”],
    fieldC: “nameC”
  }
]
```

**Case 2:**

```
{
    id: 1,
    fieldA: “nameA”,
    fieldB: [“textA”, “textB", “textC”, “textD”],
    fieldC: “nameC”
  }
```

The fieldB is an array of String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all never use `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you have no choice. Use Swift native types.

Second of all the result values in the dictionary seem to be `Int` rather than `String`.

```
...
   guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Int] else {
       throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
   }
   if let jsonA = json["A"] {
       self.labelA.text = "\(jsonA)"
   }
```

in case the values are `String`

```
...
   guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:String] else {
      throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
   }
   if let jsonA = json["A"] {
      self.labelA.text = jsonA
   }
```

**Case 1** can be parsed with the following code, the *nil coalescing operator* `??` assigns a default value in case the key does not exist.

```
   guard let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] else {
      throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
   }
   for json in jsonArray {
      let identifier = json["id"] as? Int ?? 0
      let fieldA = json["fieldA"] as? String ?? ""
      let fieldB = json["fieldB"] as? [String] ?? [String]()
      let fieldC = json["fieldC"] as? String ?? ""
  }
```

**Case 2** is a dictionary `[String:Any]` and the same as case 1 but without the array loop.

Comment: Thank you so much it works! Can you please edit your answer and make a quick examples in the case of [{A: 1, 
 B: ["text1", "text2"],
 C: 3}] and also for the case {A: 1, 
 B: 2,
 C: 3} ? thanks again!

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the case `B: ["text1", "text2"]`? And your examples are inconsistent. Please give all your examples in valid JSON strings. At the moment they are also console output of a dictionary using the print command. That makes it very difficult to distinguish string and numeric types. Edit your question then I will edit the answer.

Comment: A very helpful answer! Thank you @vadian

Comment: When I came to the case 2 it's not parsed. I did like what you said: it's the same as case 1 but it's [String:Any] instead of [[String:Any]] and without  the array loop. Can you help me please?

Comment: Change `guard let json = try ...  as? [String:Any]` and delete the line `for json in ...` and the last closing brace.

Comment: The problem was coming from the server. Your solution is correct :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Always run UI stuff on main thread:

```
if let text = json[“A”] as String {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.labelA.text = text
    }
}
```